# Android:How can I unmute the user's phone programmatically?

Tags: android

I have created an app where on button click music plays and on back press, music stops. What if the user's phone is in silent mode or muted? How can I automatically turn on user's speaker while playing these music files programmatically or how can I give an option to the user to unmute or keep it in mute???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AudioManager to unmute the phone:

```
Context context = getActivity();
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: It is showing that the context could not be unresolved

Comment: Yeah I got it using getApplicationContext() but is the less volume or no volume at all and the phone being in silent mode same?

Comment: This piece of code will work regardless of phone's current state and set volume to maximum. If you want to set the phone to silent mode use `audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`